# Cycles render in background exits with error in Blender 2.91.0, on Linuxmint

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, materials

I have now a recurring new problem: when I want do render a simple animation the program stops with following errors:

```
  File "/usr/local/blender-2.91.0-linux64/2.91/scripts/modules/addon_utils.py", line 434, in disable
    mod.unregister()
  File "/usr/local/blender-2.91.0-linux64/2.91/scripts/addons/materials_utils/__init__.py", line 193, in unregister
    bpy.utils.unregister_manual_map(materialutilities_manual_map)
  File "/usr/local/blender-2.91.0-linux64/2.91/scripts/modules/bpy/utils/__init__.py", line 994, in unregister_manual_map
    _manual_map.remove(manual_hook)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

I have disabled the material addon but to no avail. In GUI everything is ok,

Comment: Does this also happen when starting with `--factory-startup` from the terminal?

Comment: Yes, I have just tried it, - when start with:blender --factory-startup -b xxx.blend the GUI is started with default menu point VFX